# Angular Module not Registering properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm getting the following errors and hints:

```
Failed to instantiate module stable due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/nomod?p0=stable
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js:6:416
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js:24:186
    at b (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js:23:252)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js:23:495
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js:38:153
    at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js:38:1)
    at db (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js:41:272)
    at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js:19:463

Module 'stable' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

So I've tried to figure out why the registering isn't working, but I've had no luck so far.

I've got this in my .js

```
/*global angular*/
var stable = angular.module('stable',[]);

stable.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.master = {};
    $scope.login = function() {
        var loginAttempt = {
                "_userName": $scope.userName;
                "_password": $scope.userPassword;
            };
        console.log(loginAttempt);
    };
    $scope.create_account = function(user) {};
});
```

and have in my my top level html tag the "ng-app="stable"" attribute. What am I missing?

HTML code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.js"></script>

<html lang="en" >
    <br xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>

        <title>User Login</title>

        <style>
            body {
                background: rgb(210, 77, 87) !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="stable" ng-controller="mainController">

    <i><span style="color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Segoe UI Black,serif; font-size:50px; margin-left: 1%; margin-top:1%;">STABLE</span></i>
        <!-- onclick="location.href = 'http://localhost:63342/AngularJS/AccountPage.html'" removed from Create Account-->
    <button type="button" ng-click="create_user(user)" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="create_user_button" style="float:right; margin-right:2.5%; margin-top:1%;">Create Account</button><br>

    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <b><span style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 32px;">Hello! Please Sign In.</span></b><br><br>

    <input style="font-size:28px;" ng-model="userName" type="text" name="username" id="id_username" placeholder="Username" size="32" maxlength="16" /><br><br>
    <input style="font-size:28px;" ng-model="userPassword" type="password" name="password" id="id_password" placeholder="Password" size="32" maxlength="16"/><br>

    <a href="http://localhost:63342/AngularJS/PasswordPage.html" style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 16px;">Forgot Password?</a>
    <br><br>
        <!-- onclick="location.href = 'http://localhost:63342/AngularJS/MainPage.html'" removed from button -->
    <button type="submit" ng-click="login()"  class="btn btn-primary big-btn btn-lg" name="login_button" >Login</button>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your javascript file with the module 'stable' is included in your html in a script tag. You also need to ensure that your script tag to load angularjs comes before this other javascript file script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/angularjs"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/js/file"></script>
```

Hopefully this helps.  It would also be useful to post your html code that goes along with this.  If this isn't a fix.

Comment: I've added the HTML now. the js file is in the same directory as the HTML file currently

Comment: @Pedro One way that you can test to see if angular is correctly set up is to include an expression somewhere in your html.  For example in your body tag. Add {{1+2}} after your body tag and if angular is working it should show a 3.  If all you see is {{1+2}} when viewing the html then angular is not set up correctly.  I find this helpful for making sure angular works initially before you try anything else.